# How to provide choices for Laravel route parameter

Tags: php, laravel, routes

What I'm trying to accomplish is, I have a route which accepts a parameter named `type` and It accepts any value now. But I want to provide choices to accept value from, If matches the route works, otherwise It throws Not found error.

Choices are:

1. retweet
2. favorite
3. tweet

Code:

```php
Route::get('/activity/{type}/status','ActivitiesController@status');
```

ActivitiesController.php

```php
class ActivitiesController extends Controller
{
    public function status($type, Request $request)
    {
        return $request->all();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use regular expression constraints like:

```
Route::get('/activity/{type}/status','ActivitiesController@status')
    ->where('type', '(retweet|favorite|tweet)');
```

Answer (score 1):

This will check the `$type`. If it's not appropriate one, it will [redirect to 404 error page](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/errors#http-exceptions):

```
public function status($type, Request $request)
{
    if ($type != 'retweet' && $type != 'favorite' && $type != 'tweet') {
        abort(404);
    }

    return $request->all();
}
```

**Alternative:**

```
Route::get('/activity/{type}/status', function()
{
    if ($type == 'retweet' || $type == 'favorite' || $type == 'tweet') {
        $app = app();
        $controller = $app->make('ActivitiesController');
        $controller->callAction($app, $app['router'], 'status', $parameters = array());
    }
});
```

**Alternative 2:**

Only if you have just 3 types and you will not add any in future. This is stupid one, but more readable and easier to maintain:

```
Route::get('/activity/retweet/status','ActivitiesController@status');
Route::get('/activity/favorite/status','ActivitiesController@status');
Route::get('/activity/tweet/status','ActivitiesController@status');
```

Also, you could [use middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware#defining-middleware). The choice is yours. )

Comment: I know this way, but I want to filter requests on the routes site, because I have other functions too which make post requests to the same route syntax and I grab the `$type` parameter from them, and If I follow this pattern, I will have to put the checks in every function.